# Turtlebot Bringup error

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

The kubuntu was already installed on laptop, so I installed ros-electric-turtlebot, ros-electric-ros and ros-electric-apps and I configured the networks settings. But when i type "sudo service turtlebot start" I get:

"start: Job failed to start". and when I type "sudo service turtlebot stop": "stop: Unknown instance:"

This error is shown when I try to use "roslaunch turtlebot_bringup robot.launch":

> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf]:
> Cannot locate installation of package
> robot_pose_ekf: [rospack] couldn't
> find package [robot_pose_ekf].
> ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros]
> ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/opt/ros/electric/stacks]

.

Also, when I use  "roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch", i get these errors:

> [turtlebot_laptop_battery-4] process has died [pid 2985, exit code
> 1]. log files:
> /home/USERNAME/.ros/log/9db4292a-d59d-11e0-8222-74f06d20ce80/turtlebot_laptop_battery-4*.log

.

> process[turtlebot_node-3]: started
> with pid [3147] Traceback (most recent
> call last): File
> "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py",
> line 48, in import serial ImportError:
> No module named serial
> [turtlebot_node-3] process has died
> [pid 3147, exit code 1]. log files:
> /home/USERNAME/.ros/log/9db4292a-d59d-11e0-8222-74f06d20ce80/turtlebot_node-3*.log
> respawning...

Does anyone know how can I fix these errors?

Thanks in advance,

Lucas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11104/turtlebot-bringup-error/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2011-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On your robot you should install ros-diamondback-turtlebot-robot. Currently the TurtleBot software is only stable on ROS diamondback.

On your workstation computer you should install ros-diamondback-turtlebot-desktop

If you have import errors similar to what is listed above then you are most likely missing rosdeps

try:

```
rosdep install turtlebot
```

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2